# How to calculate $\int_{C_a} \frac{e^z}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

How to calculate $\int_{C_a} \frac{e^z}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$. Here, $C_a$ is a "small" circle about $a$ so that $b$ is outside of $C_a$.

Actually, if I can prove the following statement, I can calculate $\int_{C_a} \frac{e^z}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$ very easily.

On the third edition of Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, page 151 it states: For simple poles the method is even more immediate, for then the residue equals the value of the function $(z-a)f(z)$ for $z=a$.

I want to make the statement more clear. Let $g(z)=(z-a)f(z)$. I should prove $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_a}f(z)dz=g(a)$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: It seems to me that you are thinking too complicated. $h(z) = e^z/(z-b)$ is holomorphic in a disk containing $C_a$, so $\int_{C_a} \frac{h(z)}{z-a}dz$ is ... ?

Comment: @MartinR Cauchy's Theorem tells me that $\int_{C_{a}}h(z)dz=0$. But I cannot apply Cauchy's Theorem to $\int_{C_{a}}\frac{h(z)}{z-a}dz$, since $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)\frac{h(z)}{z-a}\neq0$.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @MartinR I see. Cauchy's integral formula tells me that $h(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_{a}}\frac{h(z)}{z-a}dz$
, which means $\frac{e^{a}}{a-b}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_{a}}\frac{e^{z}}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula can be applied to $h(z) = e^z/(z-b)$, which is holomorphic in disk containing $C_a$:
$$
\int_{C_a} \frac{e^z}{(z-a)(z-b)} \, dz 
= \int_{C_a} \frac{h(z)}{z-a} \, dz = 2 \pi i h(a) = \frac{2 \pi i  e^a}{a-b} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you! I meet another more difficult related question. Could you help me? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4863373/752310